# Spotify Client Credentials Flow returns unsupported grant_type

Tags: rest, spotify

I tried to retrieve a AuthToken from the Spotify API using the Credentials Flow (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/).
Even though I followed all the steps, the Response, says

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "grant_type parameter is missing"
}
```

[This is the Request Body i used and the Response i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5odmV.png)
If you are interested, this is the Request in Java:

```
HttpRequest authRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(new URI("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"))
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + Utilities.EncodeBase64(id + ":" + key))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .POST(BodyPublishers.ofString(gson.toJson(new Auth("client_credentials"))))
                .build();
```

I was expecting to get a AuthToken instead of the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `grand_type` needs to pass `x-www-form-urlencoded` in POST body in offical documentation in [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/).

[image]

Demo Code as `GetToken.java` file.

```java
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class GetToken {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String CLIENT_ID = "<your client id>";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "<your client secret>";
    
            String encodeBytes  = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET).getBytes());

            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodeBytes )
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("grant_type=client_credentials"))
                .build();
    
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response.body());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile & Run it

```
javac GetToken.java
java GetToken
```

Result
[image]

This is equivalent of a POST call by Postman.
[image]
[image]