# How to get the authorization code in spring-authorization-server using a single endpoint call?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

## Context

I am using the following to build an OAuth2 authorization server

- Spring Boot 3
- Spring Security 6
- [Spring Boot Auth Server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main) (latest version)

## Goal

To get the authorization code via an endpoint call without a redirect

## Details

So I've configured the spring authorization server as per [this guide](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/spring-authorization-server-tutorial/).
The problem is that in order to get the authorization code, I need to use a browser, go to some URL and enter my login and password there and then I get the code as part of the redirect URL.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized?code=3itgI0EhMS_gSFAEJqugIWDOMe1GPCgsWe47TTk40MxMYqq4qE3GLRSL2SqWeSUuhxPrZZgYnNXkCrbt96ycq6ln3K4K34u06VuuL2xia8N3w4xM3k0MCNeYqpBUOXAa
```

I want to skip the part with the UI and somehow just get this code using something like Postman or a Java HTTP client class.

**How can I do it ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use browser if you want to use [Authorization Code Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1)

It should be redirect URI for getting Authorization code.

```
     +----------+
     | Resource |
     |   Owner  |
     |          |
     +----------+
          ^
          |
         (B)
     +----|-----+          Client Identifier      +---------------+
     |         -+----(A)-- & Redirection URI ---->|               |
     |  User-   |                                 | Authorization |
     |  Agent  -+----(B)-- User authenticates --->|     Server    |
     |          |                                 |               |
     |         -+----(C)-- Authorization Code ---<|               |
     +-|----|---+                                 +---------------+
       |    |                                         ^      v
      (A)  (C)                                        |      |
       |    |                                         |      |
       ^    v                                         |      |
     +---------+                                      |      |
     |         |>---(D)-- Authorization Code ---------'      |
     |  Client |          & Redirection URI                  |
     |         |                                             |
     |         |<---(E)----- Access Token -------------------'
     +---------+       (w/ Optional Refresh Token)
```

If you don't want to use Browser, the [Client Credentials Flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4) is possible.
But it is application token not user token.

```
     +---------+                                  +---------------+
     |         |                                  |               |
     |         |>--(A)- Client Authentication --->| Authorization |
     | Client  |                                  |     Server    |
     |         |<--(B)---- Access Token ---------<|               |
     |         |                                  |               |
     +---------+                                  +---------------+
```

This is example the client-credential from spotify by [Java and Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75784049/spotify-client-credentials-flow-returns-unsupported-grant-type/75785311#75785311)